# "a lot of" vs. "lots of"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "I have **a lot of** friends" and "I have **lots of** friends"?

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: Here's a very closely related question that might help you: [Difference between “Lots of” and “A lot of”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/difference-between-lots-of-and-a-lot-of). It helps, generally, to Google up what you're looking for!

Answer (score 3):

By using "lots of friends" you just intensify the expression "a lot of friends". Someone can say "I have many friends" and he could intensify this by saying "I have many, many friends". But both expressions are used so often that they are almost interchangeable and the intensifying force of "lots of" has become weak.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Could you please provide a grammar source for that?

Comment: I don't think that you will find it in a grammar or a dictionary. In a grammar you will probably find "a lot of" and "lots of", but no comment about the two expressions. And Longman DCE says only "a lot of/lots of" informal, a large amount or number.- I have given my personal view.

Answer (score 1):

Both the phrases mean a large number, amount or quantity of.

So there is no difference in meaning between "I have a lot of friends" and "I have lots of friends".  These phrases are informal.  The phrase "lots of" is more informal.

They are almost interchangeable.

Comment: Both versions are informal. A formal version would be "I have many friends".

Comment: The Photon, I said "more informal" (both are informal but "lots" is more informal).

Comment: Would you say it is "a lot more informal" or "lots more informal"?

Comment: both are correct when used as an adverb.  But "a lot" is more common.