# "lot of luck'" or "lots of luck"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-choice

Are both of below sentences correct?

```
I had a lot of luck yesterday.
I had lots of luck yesterday.
```

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["a lot of" vs. "lots of"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34714/a-lot-of-vs-lots-of)

Comment: @MatthewHaugen  I saw this question before asking. But 'friend' is countable and 'luck' is not. So I thougth it is not duplicate.

Comment: Interesting. Fair enough, I'll buy that. I've retracted my close vote. But I'm leaving my comment since they're quite related, and I think that's an important distinction to be made for anyone who intends to answer this question.

Comment: *Luck* is easy, because you can't pluralise it. But all four combinations are valid with, say *"I had **a lot of trouble** then", "I had **a lot of troubles** then", "I had **lots of trouble** then", "I had **lots of troubles** then"*. In the case of "luck", I don't think there's any meaningful difference. When *negating* (as in *"I don't have a lot of luck with girls"*) it would normally be ***a lot***, not ***lots***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. Would you change this comment into answer?

Comment: Right, I think they are interchangeable in OP's exact situation.  They aren't interchangeable in:  "I'm gonna go win that big stuffed animal at the penny toss booth."  "Ok, lots o' luck with that!" you can't say, "Ok, a lot of luck with that!"

Comment: @rtruszk: A *good* answer would include the points made by both me and Jim. Probably together with other restrictions on use and/or differences in meaning. For many purposes ***a lot*** and ***lots*** are fairly interchangeable, but I'd rather see an answer covering *general* usage differences. Perhaps including usages with other "things you can have a lot/lots of" besides ***luck***.

Comment: **I'm gonna go win that big stuffed animal at the penny toss booth.** I see no problem with *Okay, a lot of luck with that!* This shows how interchangeable the two phrases are. There is basically no difference in *lots of luck* and *a lot of luck.* Both speak about a general quantity. One difference is that it is idiomatic to repeat *lots* but not *a lot*, as in *I eat lots and lots and lots of pizza.* But not *I eat a lot and a lot and a lot of pizza.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel these phrases are not interchangeable. We usually use "lots of luck" when we wish somebody, for example, I wish you lots of luck in your job! Otherwise, it doesn't sound appropriate to use this phrase in other cases like the second sentence.

So the first sentence "I had a lot of luck yesterday" is preferable.

Comment: But how is it with an other uncountable noun instead of luck? For example: "water". Every time I take a bath, I consume *a lot of* water. vs. Every time I take a bath, I consume *lots of* water.